# I have a problem with the functools.reduce() built-in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with the reduce built in function:

First I thought that `reduce()` is the built-in function but it was removed in python 3.0, but I knew that there is in python 3.0 a function like `reduce()` which was `functools.reduce()` but when I wrote it in the IDE Editor the compiler give me an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Abdulrahman Almorsy\Python\Reduce.py", line 2, in <module>

    print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,lst))

NameError: name 'functools' is not defined
```

and that was the code:

```
lst =[47,11,42,13]
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,lst))
```

Comment: Also if you just want to sum up the values of a list `sum(lst)` would be enough without any imports

Comment: I know that sum(lst) is more better but because I'm beginner in programming so I'm still learning python and that was my lesson for that time the built-in functions but because my teacher use Python 2.7 and I'm learning python 3.9 so I don't know more about python 3.0 okay??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can use a module, you need to import it. Add `import functools` at the top of your script.